# Story about alien takeover and the hero finds a way to make electrons flow in wires

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

Short story about an alien takeover.  The hero finds some mental way to make electrons flow in wires, so he has power to defeat their ships.
From a pulp magazine in early fifties.

Comment: You might get some mileage looking at the answers for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23576/whats-the-title-of-that-novel-where-an-alien-monolith-makes-the-earth-lose-elec

Comment: Kind of "Lord of Light" by R. Zelazny - Sam is able to control electrical current and other similar phenomenon. But actually aliens (native inhabitants of some distant world) were defeated by humans